# How to return response to webflux endpoint after pushing message into google cloud pubsub?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-webflux, google-cloud-pubsub

I am creating a simple spring boot app using spring integration. Below are the three main constructs of this app:

1. Inbound Gateway: WebFluxInboundEndpoint which accepts http request
2. Outbound Gateway: PubSubMessageHandler which pushes message to google cloud pubsub topic
3. Message Channel: FluxMessageChannel acting as request channel

Google cloud PubSubMessageHandler provides failure and success callback due to which error/success response is not returned back to webflux endpoint and request waits for indefinite time.

**Ask: How success/failure response can be returned back after receiving response from pubsub?**

Working copy of application is available here: https://github.com/piyushpcegarg/spring-gcp-pubsub-webflux-sample

To run application please put your google cloud service key in serviceAccountKey.json file and 
then provide environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/PATH_TO/serviceAccountKey.json

Sample request: curl -d "name=piyush" http://localhost:8080/createPerson

Below is the sample file which accepts above request and after converting into spring message, it pushes into pubsub topic "person"

```
package com.example;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.core.PubSubTemplate;
import org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.integration.outbound.PubSubMessageHandler;
import org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.support.converter.JacksonPubSubMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.MessageChannels;
import org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.integration.webflux.inbound.WebFluxInboundEndpoint;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler;
import org.springframework.util.concurrent.ListenableFutureCallback;

/**
 * Entry point into the sample application.
 *
 * @author Piyush Garg
 */
@SpringBootApplication
public class PubSubWebFluxApplication {

    private static final Log LOGGER = LogFactory.getLog(PubSubWebFluxApplication.class);

    private static final String TOPIC_NAME = "person";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PubSubWebFluxApplication.class, args);
    }

    /**
     * bean to deserialize request payload.
     */
    @Bean
    public JacksonPubSubMessageConverter jacksonPubSubMessageConverter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        return new JacksonPubSubMessageConverter(objectMapper);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel pubSubOutputChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.flux().get();
    }

    /**
     * Message handler which will consume messages from message channel.
     * Then it will send google cloud pubsub topic.
     */
    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "pubSubOutputChannel")
    public MessageHandler messageSender(PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate) {
        PubSubMessageHandler handler = new PubSubMessageHandler(pubSubTemplate, TOPIC_NAME);
        handler.setPublishCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<>() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
                LOGGER.info("There was an error sending the message.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String result) {
                LOGGER.info("Message was sent successfully.");
            }
        });

        return handler;
    }

    /**
     * Webflux endpoint to consume http request.
     */
    @Bean
    public WebFluxInboundEndpoint webFluxInboundEndpoint() {

        WebFluxInboundEndpoint endpoint = new WebFluxInboundEndpoint();

        RequestMapping requestMapping = new RequestMapping();
        requestMapping.setMethods(HttpMethod.POST);
        requestMapping.setConsumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE);
        requestMapping.setPathPatterns("/createPerson");
        endpoint.setRequestMapping(requestMapping);

        endpoint.setRequestChannel(pubSubOutputChannel());

        return endpoint;
    }
}
```

The build.gradle dependencies are:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.6.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "Hoxton.SR4")
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-integration'
    implementation 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-webflux'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

New application file after making PubSubMessageHandler as sync and adding ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice but this is giving error "'beanFactory' must not be null" when MessagingGatewaySupport creates Correlator.

```
package com.example;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.aopalliance.aop.Advice;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.core.PubSubTemplate;
import org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.integration.outbound.PubSubMessageHandler;
import org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.support.converter.JacksonPubSubMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.MessageChannels;
import org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice;
import org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.integration.webflux.inbound.WebFluxInboundEndpoint;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler;

/**
 * Entry point into the sample application.
 *
 * @author Piyush Garg
 */
@SpringBootApplication
public class PubSubWebFluxApplication {

    private static final Log LOGGER = LogFactory.getLog(PubSubWebFluxApplication.class);

    private static final String TOPIC_NAME = "person";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PubSubWebFluxApplication.class, args);
    }

    /**
     * bean to deserialize request payload.
     */
    @Bean
    public JacksonPubSubMessageConverter jacksonPubSubMessageConverter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        return new JacksonPubSubMessageConverter(objectMapper);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel pubSubOutputChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.flux().get();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel replyChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.flux().get();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel errorChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.flux().get();
    }

    /**
     * Message handler which will consume messages from message channel.
     * Then it will send google cloud pubsub topic.
     */
    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(
            inputChannel = "pubSubOutputChannel",
            adviceChain = "expressionAdvice"
    )
    public MessageHandler messageSender(PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate) {
        PubSubMessageHandler handler = new PubSubMessageHandler(pubSubTemplate, TOPIC_NAME);
        handler.setSync(true);
        return handler;
    }

    /**
     * Webflux endpoint to consume http request.
     */
    @Bean
    public WebFluxInboundEndpoint webFluxInboundEndpoint() {

        WebFluxInboundEndpoint endpoint = new WebFluxInboundEndpoint();

        RequestMapping requestMapping = new RequestMapping();
        requestMapping.setMethods(HttpMethod.POST);
        requestMapping.setConsumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE);
        requestMapping.setPathPatterns("/createPerson");
        endpoint.setRequestMapping(requestMapping);

        endpoint.setRequestChannel(pubSubOutputChannel());
        endpoint.setReplyChannel(replyChannel());
        endpoint.setErrorChannel(errorChannel());

        return endpoint;
    }

    @Bean
    public Advice expressionAdvice() {
        ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice advice = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
        advice.setSuccessChannel(replyChannel());
        advice.setFailureChannel(errorChannel());
        return advice;
    }
}
```

Stacktrace of error which is coming after sending http request:

```
2020-05-04 16:23:47.371 ERROR 59089 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [fd79ecbb-1]  500 Server Error for HTTP POST "/createPerson"

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'beanFactory' must not be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP POST "/createPerson" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Stack trace:
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.ChannelUtils.getErrorHandler(ChannelUtils.java:52) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.ReactiveStreamsConsumer.onInit(ReactiveStreamsConsumer.java:126) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.afterPropertiesSet(IntegrationObjectSupport.java:214) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.registerReplyMessageCorrelatorIfNecessary(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:799) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceiveMessageReactive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:602) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `PubSubMessageHandler` is not designed for request/reply behavior.
In most cases it is used as send-n-forget.

Since you really worry about a success/failure reply, I only can suggest something like:

1. `PubSubMessageHandler.setSync(true)`:

   ```
   /**
    * Set publish method to be synchronous or asynchronous.
    *
    * <p>Publish is asynchronous be default.
    * @param sync true for synchronous, false for asynchronous
    */
   public void setSync(boolean sync) {
   ```

This way your `PubSubMessageHandler` is going to wait for `pubsubFuture.get();` and if it fails a `MessageHandlingException` is going to be thrown.

2. To handle success or failure for this `sync` scenario i suggest to take a look into an `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` with its `successChannel` and `failureChannel`.
   Where on `onSuccessExpression` I think should `#root` pointing to a `requestMessage`.
   The `onFailureExpression` may consult an `#exception` SpEL expression variable, but still propagate a `requestMessage` to the `failureChannel`. The reason I talk about a `requestMessage` because it has that important `replyChannel` to respond to that `WebFluxInboundEndpoint` request. 
   See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#message-handler-advice-chain
3. Those `successChannel` and `failureChannel` and failure sub-flows should reply properly with some return leaving their `outputChannel` empty.

But at the same time I totally agree that it would be much easier to make that `PubSubMessageHandler` as `AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler` returning some `ListenableFuture` to let us to process a publishing result.

Comment: Thanks @Artem for advice. I have created 2 more FluxMessageChannel as replyChannel() and errorChannel(). Then attached these channels to 
WebFluxEndPoint and expressionAdvice. But while sending http request, MessagingGatewaySupport creates Correlator and it fails because beanFactory is null.
Attached new application file and stacktrace in the question for reference.

Please advice, whether I have configured expressionAdvice properly.

Comment: No, you don't need that `endpoint.setReplyChannel(replyChannel());` and therefore a dedicated channel bean. You just need to rely on the auto-created `replyChannel` header which is a `TemporaryReplyChannel` instance. Your `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` should send to some other channel which is going to reply to nothing - essentially to the mentioned `replyChannel` header. You can't also rely on the default `Message::getPayload` because you need headers from a request message which are going to contain the mentioned `replyChannel`.

Comment: As I said: with an existing `PubSubMessageHandler` behavior it is going to be a hard task to implement. you may consider something like `PublishSubscribeChannel` with `PubSubMessageHandler` as a first subscriber and something else as a second for a `success` pub/sub publishing.

Comment: For the error variant I really would stay with your `endpoint.setErrorChannel(errorChannel())`, but you still need to process that error and return something reasonable into the same `replyChannel` header.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Artem. I resolved it by providing custom request handler advice which is identifying replyChannel from message header in success scenario and sending message payload in response to weblflux endpoint.

For error scenario, I am relying on error handling mechanism of ReactiveStreamsConsumer which internally uses errorChannel to send the error back to weblflux endpoint.

Please advice whether this implementation is correct.

Below is the code for PubSubRequestHandlerAdvice:

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate;
import org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice;
import org.springframework.integration.message.AdviceMessage;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;

public class PubSubRequestHandlerAdvice extends AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice {

  private final MessagingTemplate messagingTemplate = new MessagingTemplate();

  @Override
  protected Object doInvoke(ExecutionCallback callback, Object target, Message<?> message) {

    Object result = callback.execute();

    Object evalResult = message.getPayload();
    MessageChannel successChannel = null;
    Object replyChannelHeader = message.getHeaders().getReplyChannel();
    if (replyChannelHeader instanceof MessageChannel) {
      successChannel = (MessageChannel) replyChannelHeader;
    }

    if (evalResult != null && successChannel != null) {
      AdviceMessage<?> resultMessage = new AdviceMessage<>(evalResult, message);
      this.messagingTemplate.send(successChannel, resultMessage);
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Final application file which is using PubSubRequestHandlerAdvice for PubSubMessageHandler.

```
package com.example;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.aopalliance.aop.Advice;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.core.PubSubTemplate;
import org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.integration.outbound.PubSubMessageHandler;
import org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.support.converter.JacksonPubSubMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.MessageChannels;
import org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.integration.webflux.inbound.WebFluxInboundEndpoint;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler;

/**
 * Entry point into the sample application.
 *
 * @author Piyush Garg
 */
@SpringBootApplication
public class PubSubWebFluxApplication {

    private static final Log LOGGER = LogFactory.getLog(PubSubWebFluxApplication.class);

    private static final String TOPIC_NAME = "person";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PubSubWebFluxApplication.class, args);
    }

    /**
     * bean to deserialize request payload.
     */
    @Bean
    public JacksonPubSubMessageConverter jacksonPubSubMessageConverter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        return new JacksonPubSubMessageConverter(objectMapper);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel pubSubOutputChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.flux().get();
    }

    /**
     * Message handler which will consume messages from message channel.
     * Then it will send google cloud pubsub topic.
     */
    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(
            inputChannel = "pubSubOutputChannel",
            adviceChain = "pubSubAdvice"
    )
    public MessageHandler messageSender(PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate) {
        PubSubMessageHandler handler = new PubSubMessageHandler(pubSubTemplate, TOPIC_NAME);
        handler.setSync(true);
        return handler;
    }

    /**
     * Webflux endpoint to consume http request.
     */
    @Bean
    public WebFluxInboundEndpoint webFluxInboundEndpoint() {

        WebFluxInboundEndpoint endpoint = new WebFluxInboundEndpoint();

        RequestMapping requestMapping = new RequestMapping();
        requestMapping.setMethods(HttpMethod.POST);
        requestMapping.setConsumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE);
        requestMapping.setPathPatterns("/createPerson");
        endpoint.setRequestMapping(requestMapping);

        endpoint.setRequestChannel(pubSubOutputChannel());

        return endpoint;
    }

    @Bean
    public Advice pubSubAdvice() {
        return new PubSubRequestHandlerAdvice();
    }

}
```

Working copy of application is available here: https://github.com/piyushpcegarg/spring-gcp-pubsub-webflux-sample